# Pretty Print Output with Scrapy Shell

Tags: shell, scrapy, pretty-print

I am trying to use Scrapy shell to explore the web pages before writing the crawled itself. One thing I find that it is very hard to read the Scrappy shell output. Is there anyway to make the output pretty print?

For example, running the shell with the command

```
scrapy shell http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python
```

then issue the command with the shell:

```
response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')")
```

You can see the output is all staffed into online, hard to read. Is the Scrapy shell output format JSON? How to make it readable?

Comment: can you paste your shell output? what are you expecting instead? `.css()` will output a `SelectorList` which may be a bit obscure, but you can use `.extract()` on the selector list and get actual data

Comment: maybe with ipython (`pip install ipython`)

Comment: with `.extract()`, the output looks better (all the urls are still in one line but more readable than the selector list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use firefox with firebug extension to find the right xpaths in your source code and then reformat and try it within scrapy shell.